# Can't load JS File

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to load two JS files. But some how its not working. Tried both of these, and the console window doesn't complain of unable to load the file, it never was in the head.
Also, I'm having a weird issue (not sure if related) that CSS file would not be loaded if not specified explicitly in the header. However, if specified, it would be loaded twice.

#### version 1

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_initialization' );

function theme_initialization() {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
}

function enqueue_scripts() {
    $template_dir = get_template_directory_uri();

    wp_enqueue_script( 'xxxx', $template_dir . '/js/xxxx.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'xxxx', $template_dir . '/js/xxxx.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
```

#### version 2

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
function enqueue_scripts() {
    $template_dir = get_template_directory_uri();

    wp_enqueue_script( 'xxxx', $template_dir . '/js/xxxx.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'xxxx', $template_dir . '/js/xxxx.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
```

Comment: What is the *code* in `header.php`, and what is the *browser-rendered output* of either/both of those alternatives?

Comment: @ChipBennett, it's in functions.php. Also I find it interesting that when I do get_template_directory_uri(), sometimes I get my template's path, but sometimes I get that of twentytwelve. Even though I'm not writing a child theme.

Comment: Hey Angela! Can you confirm that `wp_head()` is getting called in your `header.php` file right before the closing `</head>` tag? Also, could you confirm for me that jQuery is loading properly?

Comment: @bosco: exactly two of the things I was trying to clarify with the questions in my comment.

Comment: @bosco: yes the wp_head() is called before </head> and I can see jquery.js in the resources panel

Comment: @ChipBennett glad I'm thinking along the right lines :D .

Comment: Angela, can you further confirm that executing `jQuery` (without trailing parenthesis) in your console returns something along the lines of `function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}`? While I'm not entirely sure regarding your `get_template_directory_uri()` issue, you may be able to hack around the problem by substituting [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri). This would probably be easier to work out if, as @ChipBennett suggested, we could see the browser-rendered markup for either or both of your "versions."

Comment: @bosco: turns out I didn't include wp_foot() in the footer when I specify the scripts to be loaded on the footer :(. Problem solved. Thanks a lot of the input.

Comment: Glad it all worked out :) . Press on, Angela!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer Angela, doesn't matter that you've answered your own question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever building a theme, you should always add wp_footer(); in the footer.php right before the closing body tag to ensure all JS files that are loaded at the footer can be loaded.